# Target class [view] does not exist. in Container.php

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-7

I have a problem with laravel and I don't know how to fix it for now. Actually I don't know how I face this problem, but will try to explain you what I did and what I tried for now to fix the problem.

I tried  `composer update` and this problem occured.
Now I can not type any command like `php artisan make:livewire name`  or even `php artisan --version`, everytime when I try to execute commands I receive this error in console

```
In Container.php line 811:
                                       
  Target class [view] does not exist.  
                                       

In Container.php line 809:
                             
  Class view does not exist 

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Also the information from the log file

```
[previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class view does not exist at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:809)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(809): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#1 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(691): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#2 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#3 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(637): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#5 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1284): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#6 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(198): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->offsetGet()
#7 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(166): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::resolveFacadeInstance()
#8 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(255): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::getFacadeRoot()
#9 /var/www/vendor/beyondcode/helo-laravel/src/HeloLaravelServiceProvider.php(41): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic()
#10 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(627): BeyondCode\\HeloLaravel\\HeloLaravelServiceProvider->register()
#11 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(75): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->register()
#12 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(604): Illuminate\\Foundation\\ProviderRepository->load()
#13 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
#14 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(230): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterProviders->bootstrap()
#15 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith()
#16 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#17 /var/www/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#18 {main}
"}
```

Solutions I have been tried till now:

1.Delete `vendor` folder and type `composer install` again but at the final stage I received this error again.

2.Delete `vendor` and `composer.lock` still without success.

3.Cleaned `boostrap/cache/*.php` folder and run commands again, but it not worked again.

So any advice how to fix this problem will be appreciated.
`Laravel Version: 7`

Comment: add `-vvv` to any command you run to see if you can get a more verbose error message, perhaps a stacktrace

Comment: Try run:
`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @HarpalSingh already tried without success, still received the same error . Lagbox I did not receive more information from stacktrace after added `-vvv`

Comment: what did you do to cause this in the first place?

Comment: I tried to install one package and I received this error, and from then I'm not able to do anything

Comment: Please share more details about the problem. Can you reset your project to a state where this error does not occur? If yes, please add the differences to your post, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: what package and what does "try" mean ... what happened?

Comment: I have been tried to install this package miljar/php-exif, but I don't think it's matters. Also I can provide and one more error message `Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole problem was that, another developer had commented line
`Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,` inside `config/app.php` `providers`

Comment: Wow, you just saved me hours of debug!

Answer (score 4):

For me this error occurred after having executed `php artisan optimize:clear`.

All I had to do to fix it was to execute `php artisan view:cache`

Comment: In my case All I had to do was to execute php artisan optimize

Comment: `php artisan view:cache` works

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in my app (Laravel 8, php 7.4 online server) following the steps below:

1. access my server over ssh
2. execute this command for the installer composer:
   curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
3. change the name of composer.phar for composer.  Follow the stpes below:
   mkdir ~/bin
   mv ~/composer.phar ~/bin/composer
4. now execute this command for apache PHP
   export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/bin
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/bin' >> ~/.bashrc

Now test using the command
composer about

Perfect! Now do you need delete your folder VENDOR,  and run the command below :
composer update
Voila!   try access you application again

Answer (score -2):

One can also run `composer install` and it could also fix some versions of this error.